# How can I calculate the median of irregular datasets?

Tags: r, sequence, median, percentile

In R, I've got some data in a dataframe with the x-values in column df$a and y in column df$b. I want to interpolate them to a series of generated x-values à la `output_x_values <- seq(0.0, 100.0, 1.0)`.  Now `approx(df$a, y = df$b, xout = output_x_values)` somehow only extracts the first `length(output_x_values)` from the given df with `nrow(df) > length(output_x_values)`. What is going wrong here and what can I do to fix it? Atm it looks like as shown in the figure, and I want to add a median-line.[Fraction of precipitation by percentile.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VrLr.png)

Answer (score 1):

The approx function you are attempting to use for interpolation has a default "rule" argument that will not interpolate values outside the observed range in the vector which is truncating the values in the result with NA. You can change this to "rule = 2" in order to allow for interpolation outside of the expected range:

```
output_x_values <- seq(0.0, 100, 1.0)

# Toy data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a = seq(50, 150, 10), b = seq(0, 100, 10) + rnorm(11, 20, 10))

df

# a         b
# 1   50  13.73546
# 2   60  31.83643
# 3   70  31.64371
# 4   80  65.95281
# 5   90  63.29508
# 6  100  61.79532
# 7  110  84.87429
# 8  120  97.38325
# 9  130 105.75781
# 10 140 106.94612
# 11 150 135.11781

approx(x = df$a, y = df$b, xout = output_x_values, rule = 2)
```

However, this has a slightly odd effect on the data:

```
plot(df)
plot(approx(x = df$a, y = df$b, xout = output_x_values, rule = 2))
```

You may wish to try:

```
# Toy data scaled with centiles but without interpolation
plot(percent_rank(df$a), percent_rank(df$b))

# Toy data scaled with centiles with interpolation
plot(approx(x = percent_rank(df$a), y = percent_rank(df$b), n = 100))
```